# style an html element using object constructor

Tags: javascript, css, constructor

I'm practicing using constructor function/objects. I want to style some `div`s with CSS dynamically using this type of object. I'm trying to get the `div`s with `document.getElementById` but am not able to style them. I'm getting the error message 'cannot set backgroundColor of undefined'. It seems i'm not actually getting the element I want or it's not being saved to the variable.

How can I get the element and pass it through the construtor function?

```
<div id='div1'>div1</div>
<div id='div2'>div2</div>

function StyleDiv(id) {
document.getElementById('id');
this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
this.style.height = '110px';
this.style.width = '110px';
}

var div1st = new StyleDiv('div1');
var div2nd = new StyleDiv('div2');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the idea slightly wrong. When you use `document.getElementById` you must store a reference to the element it returns. So for example this would be how you select an element:

```
var id = 'div1';
var element = document.getElementById(id);
```

Then to style it you can use:

```
element.style.width = '110px';
```

To maintain a public reference to the element try this code:

```
function StyleDiv(id) {
    this.element = document.getElementById(id); 
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    this.element.style.height = '110px';
    this.element.style.width = '110px';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to the selected element in a variable, and then use that variable when setting the styling:

```
function StyleDiv(id) {
   var elm = document.getElementById(id); 
   elm.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
   elm.style.height = '110px';
   elm.style.width = '110px';
}
```

*Note that I also removed the quotes around `id` in `getElementById(id)`*

**About "this"**

The `this` keyword can be a bit troublesome to understand in JavaScript initially. Here is a [good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) that will explain it a bit further.

With the help of that article, I believe you will be able to create a more object oriented approach to all this. You might want have the element as a public property of the instance perhaps, or expose a public method to set styles on that element.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the DOM node to a variable and use that to change the style. Also, remove the quotes around `id` since it's a reference to the argument that you're passing in to the function.

```
function StyleDiv(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  el.style.height = '110px';
  el.style.width = '110px';
}
```